# Convert a date stamp with hour from edt to gmt using datetime module

Tags: datetime, perl

I have the following script that I'm using to try to convert a date stamp, with hour, from edt to gmt time.  I'm using the datetime module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $watermark = "2023081410";
my $parseesthour = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d%H', time_zone => 'America/New_York');
my $parsegmthour = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d%H', time_zone => 'GMT');

$watermark = $parseesthour->parse_datetime($watermark);
$watermark->set_formatter($parseesthour);
print "\nwatermark before -  $watermark\n";
my $watermarkgmt = $parsegmthour->parse_datetime($watermark);
$watermarkgmt->set_formatter($parsegmthour);
print "\nwatermark  after -  $watermarkgmt\n";
```

the answer from the script is the same for both dates:

watermark before -  2023081410

watermark  after -  2023081410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a DateTime object change its timezone using `set_time_zone`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $watermark = "2023081410";

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d%H', time_zone => 'America/New_York');

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($watermark);
say $dt;

$dt->set_time_zone('UTC');

say $dt;
```

If you want to keep the original object around use `clone`

```
my $dt_utc = $dt_ny->clone->set_time_zone('UTC');
```

The method `set_formatter` only makes it so that the DateTime object is formatted as desired when stringified (for example when printed).  This may be what you want, but it doesn't change the timezone of the object.

Comment: If suitable, can parse and build an object in one call,    `my $dt = DateTime::Format::Strptime -> new(pattern => '%Y%m%d%H', time_zone => 'America/New_York') -> parse_datetime($watermark);`

Comment: @JamesFinnegan Welcome :)   Let me know if questions come up